# Python threading.Semaphore vs asyncio.Semaphore

Tags: python, multithreading

I recently noticed there are two different Semaphore implementations in different packages in python, one is in `threading` package and another is in `asyncio` package. And I am curious what is the difference between these two implementation? If in async function I try to use Semaphore from `threading` package, would that cause any potential problems?

And by checking python official documentation, it wrote

```
asyncio primitives are not thread-safe, therefore they should not be used for OS thread synchronization (use threading for that)
```

But what does that mean by saying `asyncio primitives are not thread-safe and should not be used for OS thread sync`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just for completeness, there is a third type of `Semaphore` in the `multiprocessing` module. The same condition applies in the answers below - use the correct type of semaphore for the form of concurrency being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole goal of a semaphore is to provide exclusive access to something.  Only one "piece of code" can access own the semaphore at any one time.

What I mean by "piece of code" in the previous statement depends on whether I'm using multi-threading, multi-processing, or asyncio.  And the means by which you guarantee exclusive access depends on what I'm using.

Asyncio is the most restricted kind of multi-threading.  Everything is running within a single Python thread.  The Python interpreter is only executing one thing at a time.  Each "piece of code" runs until it voluntarily waits for something to happen.  Then another "piece of code" is allowed to run.  Eventually the original piece of code runs again when the thing it was waiting on happens.

With multithreading, multiple pieces of code are running within the Python interpreter.  Only one piece of code runs at any time, but they are not politely waiting for each other.  Python switches from "piece of code" to "piece of code" as it wants.

With multiprocessing, multiple Pythons are running simultaneously.
There is no sharing between the pieces of code, other than what is provided by the operating system. To set up a semaphore usually requires some support from the operating system to create a shared variable that all threads/processes can access.

So.  Asyncio primitives are designed so that they are all run within a single Python process with the processes cooperating.  They are not designed to work if multiple pieces of code try to use it simultaneously.

I hope this helps.

Comment: No, multithreading does not run "multiple Pythons simultaneously". (In fact, due to the GIL, only one thread is ever running Python code anyway; native code or other code that releases the GIL can run.)

Comment: You're right.   I was trying not to get too complicated, but I oversimplified.  See new version.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a choice which queue or which semaphore you use. They are not compatible.

Even if they both offer concurrency, `asyncio` and multi-threading are two really quite different worlds based on different principles and APIs, have different typical use-cases, etc.

Development of multi-threaded programs is not easy and a Python feature called GIL makes them not so efficient as they could be. This makes asyncio the preferred choice unless you are forced to use multi-threading.

---

Having said that, both approaches can be used in a single program.

It is possible - but not common - to run an async code in one of the threads of a multi-threaded application. The quoted notice from the docs reminds you that almost all async operations must be performed within that one thread. There are only few specialized [thread-safe low-level scheduling functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading).

For completness, the `asyncio` library can utilize a thread pool for its internal use, beacuse so-called blocking operations should not be performed by async programs.

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors, using `threading.Semaphore` for coroutines may lead to deadlocks. For example,

```py
import asyncio
from threading import BoundedSemaphore
import time

async def foo():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("waiting on asyncio.sleep(1)")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("foo")


async def main(sem: BoundedSemaphore) -> None:
    print("before acquire")
    sem.acquire()
    await foo()
    sem.release()


sem = BoundedSemaphore(1)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(main(sem), main(sem), main(sem)))
```

This will hangs forever because the second coroutine is blocked on `sem.acquire()` while the semaphore is waiting to be released by the first coroutine. With the semaphore from `threading`, the second coroutine will not yields control back so that the first coroutine can release the semaphore.